# Use LINQ to query nested OData collection

Tags: linq, odata, netflix

I'm playing around with the new [Netflix OData feed](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/OData_Catalog) (http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/) and having some issues.  I'm trying to learn LINQ at the same time but having difficulty doing what I thought was going to be quite simple.

I'd like to return a list of Titles that match a given Genre.  The Titles object contains a collection of Genres.  I'm not sure how to write this query.  My attempt below does not appear to work using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

```
from t in Titles
where t.Genres.Name.Contains("ABC")
select t
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get my results using the LINQ:

```
from g in Genres
from t in g.Titles
where g.Name == "Horror"
select t
```

This way I don't need to use Expand.  I can also use the URL: [http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Genres('Horror')/Titles()](http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Genres%28%27Horror%27%29/Titles%28%29) to get the same results.  This [post](http://www.chriswoodruff.com/index.php/2010/03/22/odata-does-not-support-select-many-queries/) by Chris Woodruff helped me understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving an DataServiceQueryException along with the message: *Request version '1.0' is too low for the response. The lowest supported version is '2.0'*.

You need to upgrade your version of .Net to .Net [Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en) and download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) for .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: I'm using LINQPad v4.13.4 which I believe is the .net 4 version.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle,
This will get you a listing of all movies by Genre

```
(from g in Genres.Expand("Titles")
where g.Name == "Horror"
select g).Dump();
```

This creates the following URL in LinqPad

```
/Catalog/Genres('Horror')?$expand=Titles
```

Its interesting that I needed to use the `.Expand` syntax to get it.
When I browse to the netflix odata feed with my browser and want the same data I can get it with the following URL: http://netflix.cloudapp.net/Catalog/Genres('Horror')/Titles

There must be a way to get at it without `.Expand`

Comment: You wrote Kyke, instead of Kyle